# Forking inside if dilemma

Tags: c, linux, fork

What happens if I call:

```
if (fork() == fork())
   //do something
```

Do both parents and both children enter the statement or what's the procedure in this case?

Comment: I suspect that only the grandchild will enter the statement. Have you tried the experiment?

Comment: i did not, because i don't really know how to test it and how to conclude useful information from the test

Comment: Not a fan of `printf`, eh?

Comment: what should I print? pid?

Comment: Yes, you should print the PIDs.  You shoudl revise the statement to capture the values returned by `fork()` (chalk one up for C's flexibility): `pid_t pid1, pid2; if ((pid1 = fork()) == (pid2 = fork()) {…}`.  Now you've got two PID values in each of the four processes and you can print them to see what goes on.  You might want to print the result of `getpid()` too — and maybe `getppid()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With two forks, you'll end up with four processes: one parent, two children, and one grandchild.

The order that the two forks happen isn't defined since C doesn't require expressions to be evaluated left to right. In the end it won't matter which happens first, so let's pretend the left `fork()` happens first. When that happens you'll end up with one parent and one child. The parent will get the child's PID back, and the child will get `0`.

Let's call the parent `A` and the child `B`. Here's what those two processes will look like after the left fork executes:

```
A          if (<pidof B> == fork())
|
+--B       if (0 == fork())
```

Now each of them will execute the right fork. Two processes become four. Let's call `B`'s new child `C` and `A`'s new child `D`. Again, each `fork()` call will return one of two values: the new child's PID in the parent process, or 0 in the child process. Here's what our four processes will then become:

```
A          if (<pidof B> == <pidof D>)
|
+--B       if (0 == <pidof C>)
|  |
|  +--C    if (0 == 0)
|
+--D       if (<pidof B> == 0)
```

As it happens, process `C` will be the only one that passes the `if` check.

Answer (score 1):

Try this experiment:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("beginning\n");

  if(fork() == fork())
    {
      printf("two are equal\n");
    }

  printf("done\n");

  return 0;
}
```

One process prints "beginning", four print "done" and one prints "two are equal". Does this clear things up?